# BGA Underfill Problem

Tags: bga, hot-air, rework

The problem is that when I heat an underfill chip to reflow it, the solder tends to boil and come out of the sides causing shorts and other problems.

Does anyone know how to prevent that and why it actually occurs?

Comment: Solder boils? At what temperature are you cooking that thing? White hot glowing?

Comment: Check the data sheet, there is usually a section for a re-flow/soldering profile. A couple of things that come to mind are: too high temperature for too long and/or too much solder.

Comment: It's happened on iPhone boards. Temp I was using was 365c on my hot air which for my setup. It wasn't an attempt to solder a new BGA in place I was trying to reflow an existing one.

Comment: BGA is notoriously difficult to work and rework with hand tools.  The key to marginal success will be lots of trial and error, and patience.  Even then, you should expect a high failure rate.  If this doesn't fit the plan, rethink the plan.

Comment: It isn't the solder that's boiling, it's residual flux or other contaminants. This wouldn't be as much of a problem if the chip weren't underfilled. I don't think there's much you can do about it if it is. You could try baking the board at 125C for a while to drive off any moisture first.

Comment: @DaveTweed So you're saying moisture is trapped under the BGA and when heat is applied it causes the solder balls to come out? I do hear small popping sounds as the solder squeezes out. Wouldn't underfill prevent any moisture or contaminants from getting under the chip?

Comment: What could be happening is that rapid heating is causing small amounts of trapped moisture to flash to steam and exit violently. By baking at a lower temperature, you can drive off the excess moisture more slowly so that it can escape without causing damage. Once the moisture is baked off, you can hopefully heat up to reflow temperatures without any breakage. May or may not work, but it is worth a try.

Comment: That popping sound you hear may be popcorn effect: http://anysilicon.com/msl-and-popcorn-effect/ PCBs can delaminate if not pre-baked depending on where it has been and for how long due to moisture build-up as well.